# Adding JSTL to jsp (Tomcat 8)

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jstl

I want to use the JSTL library in my jsp's. Now I followed a tutorial and it told me to add this line to the jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

It gives me the error cannot resolve taglib with uri and then the URL.

I'm running tomcat 8. My web.xml is like this:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add jar for the `jstl` library in your classpath. If you are using maven, then add this dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Add this to your pom.xml.

Comment: Thank you :-) this solved the problem. I used the wrong dependency http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ctaglibs%7Cc%7C1.1.2%7Cjar

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this issue, you would need to do the following:

- The **jstl.jar** should be in your classpath. (Download [jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/jstl/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar) / [pom](http://central.maven.org/maven2/jstl/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.pom))
- Make sure you have the following taglib directive at the top of your jsp:

  ```
  <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
  ```

Comment: Can I add them via maven? Because I tried but then it still failed. I included this one http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ctaglibs%7Cc%7C1.1.2%7Cjar

Comment: Yes see [this](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2) for maven dependency.