# DispatcherServlet: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlet-mapping

Running my project in STS gives on a Tomcat gives me the error:

```
Mai 19, 2016 4:44:52 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNUNG: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/CloudService/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'
Mai 19, 2016 4:45:35 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNUNG: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/CloudService/HelloWeb/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'
Mai 19, 2016 4:48:13 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNUNG: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/CloudService/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'
```

I checked out nearly every relevant article on stackoverflow already, but I just cant fix my problem.

src/main/java/HelloController.java

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

      return "hello";
   }

}
```

WebContent/WEB-INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.stackoverflow" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>CloudService</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which exactly of those weren't helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22No+mapping+found+for+HTTP+request+with+URI%22+%22in+DispatcherServlet+with+name%22 Sorry for so many duplicates, but [spring] doesn't seem to have any caretakers who want to curate a valuable knowledge base.

Comment: It looks that you failed to bootstrap a spring context... In XML config, web.xml commonly contains a `<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>` bloc for that usage, that will by default use a (possibly declaring no beans) applicationContext.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration looks ok. However you are requesting for the /CloudService/ url which is not mapped to any controller handler method. Your Controller has a handler for /CloudService/hello instead. You can either include a handler for / or if both / and /hello should be handled by the same method you can do it this way

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({"/hello" , "/"})
public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

      return "hello";
   }

}
```

N.B Your application has one application context HelloWeb-servlet.xml therefor you don`t need a ContextLoaderListener configuration to create a parent context.However as soon as you have service beans which must be separated into a different context you need to configure it

Comment: I have changed the code as you suggested and I get: HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config - when I call: http://localhost:8080/CloudService/hello/ What else could I do wrong?

Comment: You need to ensure that you include the jstl library in your classpath. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026991/adding-jstl-to-jsp-tomcat-8

Answer (score 0):

This is one sample web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

This is dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
   ">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class ="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="shape" class="shapes.Shape">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value ="12" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" value ="2" />
    </bean>
    <import resource="spring-dao.xml"/>
 </beans>
```

I am sure this should work for you as well.